# Google API PHP Client causing my hash to produce different result

Tags: php, hash, sha256, google-api-php-client

I'm using sha256 on my hash, but when i include google api php client https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/, somehow my hash is changed

so

```
include 'google-api-php-client.php';
$my_hash = hash('sha256', $my_salted_data);
```

will produce different result from

```
$my_hash = hash('sha256', $my_salted_data);
```

Do you guys know what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem is, After I see Google API PHP Client source code, i found that the script will set default timezone to UTC if not defined in `php.ini` and my hash algorithm use `date` function using different timezone, so my hash will produce different result